# Why does my while code cause my simulator to crash?

Tags: while-loop, lua, coronasdk

Whenever I add the while code to my game, the simulator stops responding. I know its the while code that causes this problem because if I take the while code out, the game works like its supposed to. Whats wrong with my while code, and how do i fix it? Let me know if you need any more information to solve the problem. Here is the code:

```
function scene:createScene ( event )
local group = self.view

local tap = display.newText("Tap:", 0, 0, "Helvetica", 36)
tap.x = 100
tap.y = screenTop + 20
group:insert(tap)

local imageFiles = {"redbox.png", "bluebox.png"}
local imageFile = imageFiles[math.random(2)]
local randomImage = display.newImage(imageFile, centerX, screenTop + 20) 

local button1 = display.newImage("redbox.png")
button1.x = centerX
button1.y = centerY
group:insert(button1)

local button2 = display.newImage("bluebox.png")
button2.x = centerX
button2.y = centerY - 100
group:insert(button2)

local function endGame(event)
if imageFile == "redbox.png" then
button1.x = math.random( 55, 300)
button1.y = math.random( 55, 300)
button2.x = math.random( 55, 300)
button2.y = math.random( 55, 300)
local imageFile = imageFiles[math.random(2)]
local randomImage = display.newImage(imageFile, centerX, screenTop + 20)
while imageFile == "redbox.png" do
if imageFile ~= "redbox.png" then
storyboard.gotoScene( "restartEasy" )

end
end
end
end

local function endGame2(event)
if imageFile == "bluebox.png" then
button1.x = math.random( 55, 300)
button1.y = math.random( 55, 300)
button2.x = math.random( 55, 300)
button2.y = math.random( 55, 300)
local imageFile = imageFiles[math.random(2)]
local randomImage = display.newImage(imageFile, centerX, screenTop + 20)
while imageFile == "bluebox.png" do
if imageFile ~= "bluebox.png" then
storyboard.gotoScene("restartEasy")

end
end
end
end

button1:addEventListener("tap", endGame)
button2:addEventListener("tap", endGame2)

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know why you are using while and the if statement unnecessarily, try   this it should work.

```
 local function endGame(event)
  if imageFile == "redbox.png" then
   button1.x = math.random( 55, 300)
   button1.y = math.random( 55, 300)
   button2.x = math.random( 55, 300)
   button2.y = math.random( 55, 300)
   local imageFile = imageFiles[math.random(2)]
   local randomImage = display.newImage(imageFile, centerX, screenTop + 20)

   else 
   storyboard.gotoScene( "restartEasy" )

 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar! The reason why i had it so complicated was that I was trying to loop two functions together based on the randomly generated image that appears on the top... any ideas on how to do that?